# wxPython: CustomTreeCtrl disable checking for event EVT_KEY_DOWN

Tags: python, file, module, tree, wxpython

I am currently using CustomTreeCtrl instead of the regular TreeCtrl because it allows me to have checkbox / radio button with the tree nodes.

However, I realize the control itself catches event EVT_KEY_DOWN (whenever any key is pressed) to look for any matching tree nodes. I need the event EVT_KEY_DOWN for other purposes, so is there a way to disable the tree control from recognizing EVT_KEY_DOWN?

Or would it work if I create my own CustomTreeCtrl that does not have self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.onKeyDown) inside? How would I locate that Python file then (wx.lib.agw.customtreectrl) on Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`treeCtrl.Unbind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN)`

I think would work :P

Comment: it should be just treeCtrl.Unbind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN), but thanks!